# Chrome does not display some console.log messages when debbuger is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I am uploading video file and want to see the progress. For debug, i am using :

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt){ console.log('progress', evt.loaded/evt.total*100) };
```

When the chrome debugger is open, these progress messages are not displayed but other console.log messages are.

When the chrome debugger is closed all console.log are displayed including the "progress" messages:

```
    success.orderid=  OK END
20:56:59.183 Test:165 2
20:56:59.590 Test:165 Fin de lecture de la vidéo
20:56:59.592 Test:269 xhr
20:56:59.592 Test:271 xhr created
20:56:59.592 Test:272 xhr.upload existe
20:57:01.616 Test:274 progress 0.10959526385110777
20:57:01.818 Test:274 progress 0.8767621108088621
20:57:01.918 Test:274 progress 1.917917117394386
20:57:02.020 Test:274 progress 3.8495336427701603
20:57:02.119 Test:274 progress 4.918087465318461
```

Have an idea of this behaviour ?

Comment: Have you got the messages filtered at all?

Comment: there is no filter at all

Comment: Can you provide more of your code, specifically the xhr initialization and upload code?